# why ejs displays file.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, foreach

I have the following error

```
TypeError: C:\Users\USER PC\Documents\Prime_News_Hub\views\Top_Stories.ejs:27
25| 

26|                         <% if(file){ %>
```

> > 27|                             <% file.forEach((docs) => { %>

```
28|                             <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 col-xxl-3 p-2' id='bootsrap'>

29|                                 <div class="box-cnt">

30|
```

file.forEach is not a function

here is my controller
const Top_Stories = (req, res) => {
var Cursor = db.collection(' article_meta_dataschemas').find({})

```
Cursor.forEach(docs => {res.render('Top_Stories', {file: docs});})
```

}

Here is my home ejs page
<% if(file){ %>
<% file.forEach((docs) => { %>

```
                                <div class="id" style="display: none;">
                                    <%- docs.User_id %> %>
                                </div>
                                <div class="author_cnt">
                                    <%- docs.UserName %> %>
                                </div>
                                <div class="img_cnt">
                                    <%- docs.Thumbnail %> %>
                                </div>
                                <div class="title_cnt">
                                    <%- docs.Title %> %>
                                </div>
                                <div class="traffic_cnt">
                                    
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    <% }) %>
                    <% } else { %> 
                        <p>no files to show</p>
                    <% } %>
```

This does not happen when i use mongoose driver to query data from database, Can I please know why this happens

Answer (score 0):

Replace
`<% file.forEach((docs) => { %>`

With
`<% for (let docs of file) { %>`